# Setting a custom indicator for ExpandableListView isn't working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, expandablelistview

So I'm trying to set a custom ExpandableListView indicator icon but it isn't working. I created an icon and saved it to drawable folder. Here are the icons:

[image] [image]

This is the selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up" android:state_empty="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

ExpandableListView xml:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/custom_arrow" />
```

However, when I launch the app, there is not indicator at all. Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: I might be mistake but wouldnt the up arrow only show if the list item has no children ie. `state_empty` and down arrow only when the list item has been set as activated?

Comment: Looks like I did use the wrong "commands" there. But how do I fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" />
</selector>
```

you wanted the `state_expanded` for when the row gets expanded and then any other state besides expanded is just the normal down arrow. You should however handle the `state_empty` when there is nothing to expand to

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to add this one line to your selector and change the arrow down condition:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up" android:state_empty="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up" />
</selector>
```